# For std::istream::ignore, could you set it to skip an infinite number of characters until delim is reached?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need my program to delete comments from the text, however, since comments could be pretty long, it would be hard to determine the right value for the count. Is it possible to use ignore() in this way, or should I look for another function?

Comment: [This `ignore` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) shows the common way to set the max number of characters to ignore. But remember that `ignore` can only use a single-character delimiter, so using it for e.g. C-comments (matching a string like `"*/"`) can't be done. One-line comments are easy though.

Comment: I try to convince my colaborators (and me) to _insert_ comments into code. Removing comments was never an issue... ;-)